# Implementing a REST API w/ Google App Engine

Tags: php, rest, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have already created a REST API w/ the Slim framework (php microframework), which is basically a few php files in a ftp server, and a SQL table.

I want to implement this very simple configuration with Google Api Engine, and there's so much resources and confusing pages in the google tutorials I can't seem to find what I'm looking for...

Can someone steer me to the right direction please ? Again, just a few php files (w/ Slim) and a sql database, that's it.
Thank you very much.

Comment: There are lots of resources explaining this. Show us,what official docs arent clear and why

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I would begin with the PHP tutorial for Google App Engine, that you can find here [1](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/introduction).

Try to deploy your existing app there, but be aware that the PHP runtime is still in Beta. Also your app will execute in a restricted "sandbox" environment [2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/).

Hope it helps.